# Splitting PDF to png

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rmagick

I'm using paperclip to upload a pdf. Once the file is uploaded I need to split every page into a png. This is the command I think I need to use

convert -size 640x300 fileName.pdf slide.png

Now if I run that command from terminal it works fine, but I need a way of getting each slides name so I can add it into a model.

What's the best way to achieve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2581679/pdf-to-png-processor-paperclip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `command` to execute system commads
(`-quotes)

`convert -size 640x300 fileName.pdf slide.png`

Comment: I am using paperclip, so wouldn't I want to use the Paperclip.run command?

Using command to execute it still leaves me with my initial problem as well, how do I  get all the file names?

Comment: Attaches.all.each{|attach| \`convert -size 640x300 #{attach.your_file_name} #{attach.your_file_name}.png\`} - you can execute system commands in model callbacks like after_save and so on. So you can convert your pdfs right after saving your attach

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to have Paperclip do this conversion for you at the time of the upload, like this:

```
has_attached_file :pdfupload, :styles => { :pinged => ["640x300", :png] }
```

Then you can show the PNG version like so:

```
<%= image_tag @mymodel.pdfupload.url(:pinged) %>
```

(Obviously the name of the model and file will need to be changed to match yours.)

Comment: I didn't know that I can set image fromat in styles. Cool feature.